# Firebase Dynamic link: How to get the URI scheme from the dynamic link that gets generated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, uri-scheme, firebase-dynamic-links

My requirement is to get the `URI` scheme out of the dynamic link `URL` that has been generated. Even in the `firebase` sample app, its the deep link url that gets returned and not the URI scheme.

For eg:

- Our dynamic link url is this -> https://my-app-code.app.goo.gl/value.
- iOS custom app scheme (added from advanced options): myappscheme://some-tag/some-tag-id
- Long dynamic link url is -> https://my-app-code.app.goo.gl/?link=my-web-url&apn=id&isi=android-google-play-id&ibi=ios-bundle-id&ius=ios-custom-app-scheme

When i click on the dynamic link url from email/notes (https://my-app-code.app.goo.gl/value), the callback will be the continueuseractivity function and i use the following block -

```
BOOL handled = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] handleUniversalLink:incomingUrl completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink, NSError * _Nullable error)
```

to get the url (dynamicLink.url). In this block, i get the deep link url which is this
-> my-web-url (which is a part of the link parameter in the long dynamic link which i have mentioned above).

**My actual requirement is to get the URI scheme myappscheme://some-tag/some-tag-id which associated with the URL. How do i get this?**

I even tried the below -

```
FIRDynamicLink *dynamicLink =  [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:url];
```

In either cases, I do not get the URI scheme.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**What you are trying to do is not currently possible on iOS with Dynamic Links.** You are confusing URI *scheme* (`myappscheme://`) with URI *path* (`myappscheme://some-tag/some-tag-id`).

To my knowledge, Dynamic Links on iOS only support the scheme (via the `ius` param). This is confusing because Android does support a URI path (via the `al` param). For iOS, you'll need to do your routing based on the deep link URL.

Alternatively, you could investigate a more robust deep linking platform like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team). Branch does support custom link parameters containing any data you wish, including a custom URI path.

Answer (score 1):

What Alex said is correct. It is not possible, but there is an easy workaround to this.

I appended my desired custom url deep link as a query parameter to the https link url I provided.

So in your case it would look something like this

https://my-app-code.app.goo.gl/?link=https://my-web-url.com/?myCustomSchemeUri%3Dmy-custom-scheme://my-custom-scheme-url&apn=id&isi=android-google-play-id&ibi=ios-bundle-id&ius=ios-custom-app-scheme

When the continueuseractivity callback gets to your app you can retrieve myCustomSchemeUri parameter from the query string and use it as you please.

Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler {

BOOL handled = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks]
                handleUniversalLink:userActivity.webpageURL
                completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink,
                             NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    // ...
                    NSURL *url = dynamicLink.url;
                    NSString *myUri = [url queryParameterValueWithName:@"customUri"];
                    if (myUri.lenghth > 0){
                        NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myUri];
                        if (myURL != nil){
                            //source application is your bundle id in this case
                            [self application:application openURL:myURL sourceApplication:@"com.yourbundle.id" annotation:@{}];
                        }
                    }
                }];
return handled;
}
```

And this is the method I wrote as a category of NSURL to retrieve the parameter

```
- (NSString *)queryParameterValueWithName:(NSString*)name{
NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:self
                                            resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
NSArray *queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems;
NSString *param = [self valueForKey:name
                      fromQueryItems:queryItems];
return param;
}

- (NSString *)valueForKey:(NSString *)key
       fromQueryItems:(NSArray *)queryItems
{
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name=%@", key];
NSURLQueryItem *queryItem = [[queryItems
                              filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]
                             firstObject];
return queryItem.value;
}
```

Maybe this answer is a bit late to you, but I ran into this problem just today.
Anyway I hope this helps somebody else out there.

Cheers,

Alessio